# How to test with toMatchImageSnapshot using vitest and react?

Tags: reactjs, testing, vite, vitest

I am creating an app using Vite, React and Typescript. I am using Vitest for testing.

https://vitest.dev/guide/snapshot.html#image-snapshots suggests that I can use Vitest for visual regression tests too, but I am having a hard time understanding how to set it up. Could someone help?

I am able to build and run the app, just the visual testing which I am trying to understand.

My react component `Header.tsx` is as follows:

```
function Header() {
 return(<div>...</div>)
}
export default Header;
```

My test file `Header.test.tsx`:

```
import { describe, it, expect, vi, afterEach } from "vitest";
import { render, screen, fireEvent, cleanup } from "@testing-library/react";
import Header from "./Header";
import { toMatchImageSnapshot } from "jest-image-snapshot";

describe(); // other functional tests, which pass

describe("Snapshot tests", () => {
    it("renders correctly", async () => {
      render(
        <Provider store={store}>
          <Header />
        </Provider>
      );
      expect(await generateImage()).toMatchImageSnapshot();
    });
  });
```

This test just times out. Am I missing something? I do not understand how is the image snapshot generated.

I am unable to find enough documentation for Vitest, specifically.

Comment: I don't see where is `generateImage` declared?